# Get only href beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have the following soup

```
<a href="https://www.abc1.com">
    <h3>ABC1</h3>
</a>
<a href="https://www.abc2.com">
    <h3>ABC2</h3>
</a>
<a href="https://www.abc3.com">
   <h3>ABC3</h3>
</a>
```

From this, I want to get all hrefs
For now, I am doing

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
```

But this is showing empty arrays,
like this,

```
[][][]
```

Anyone one who knows a better way to do this?

Comment: What is linkWithTitles ? Add the complete code

Comment: It's a soup I actually named it with my preference.

Comment: @UditHariVashisht Please have a look at the question again

Answer (score 0):

I could get the href using the following code :-

```
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cont =  soup.find_all('a')

link = []
for href in cont:
    print(link.append(href.get('href')))

#o/p
link
['https://www.abc1.com', 'https://www.abc2.com', 'https://www.abc3.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the lib before

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("https://yourwebsite")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
links = []

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```